# Apache2, несколько доменов, NodeJS и порты

Tags: node.js, apache2

На одном сервере установлен Apache2 и NodeJS.
VirtualHost настроены несколько доменов.
И вот такая ситуация: 
Для каждого доменного имени, если указать порт, открывается приложение NodeJS висящее на этом порту (domain1.com:8888, domain2.comL:8888 итд.).
Вопрос: как это исправить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Для хоста на линукс, попробуйте воспользоваться правилами `iptables`:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8888 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

Для сохранения правил можно воспользоваться [разными способами](https://qna.habr.com/q/34551).